# How to create production build folder in react?

Tags: html, css, node.js, sql-server, reactjs

I am currently working on a website using react as frontend and node js as backend. However, I have no idea how I should upload it to the live server. From my own research, I found out that I have to create a build folder. Before getting into my point in detail I want to explain how I set up the folder. So basically I have created a folder(FRONTEND name of the folder) that contains all react code and right outside the FRONTEND FOLDER, I have created server.js along with package JSON and etc. Do I have to create one build folder for the frontend and a separate build folder for the backend? Or is there a way to create one build folder for both? Also, I am running react and node js with nodemon at the same time. I would be really appreciated it if anyone can give me an idea.

Thank you

Comment: Maybe you can look for a boiler plate like this - https://github.com/Bikranshu/express-react-boilerplate

Answer (score 0):

There's many ways you can do this, but for a simple node backend which handles API requests and ALSO serves the frontend files, you do have the correct setup. Assuming you are serving a SPA or simple site, you just want to configure node to serve static files from the FRONTEND folder, and to default to FRONTEND/index.html (or whatever your app page is).

See this great example of a simple setup like this: https://daveceddia.com/deploy-react-express-app-heroku/

If you are using express, your code might look something like this:

```js
// Serve static assets
// The if statement is not necessary, it just makes it simpler
// for you to continue using your nodemon setup in development
// by only serving the static files in production.
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  // Set static folder
  app.use(express.static('FRONTEND/build'));
  app.get('*', (req, res) =>
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'FRONTEND', 'build', 'index.html'))
  );
}
```

Note that normally 'FRONTEND' would be name something like 'client', but there's no reason why FRONTEND won't work really.

So in this way, your nodejs runs at the startpoint, and sets up a route for ANY file (that's the *app.get('*'* part) to point to your react folder's app file, which resides in the build folder.

Your dev version of your react app does not run out of the build folder, so before you upload everything you would run **npm run build** to generate a production version of your site. Of course, if you're using a service such as heroku, it may be better to upload the files and have the server run the react build, but it should work either way.